# Where to put a background script

Tags: scripting, background-process

I have a script that i want to be constantly running in the background but I don't know where to launch it from

If I put it in `.bashrc` it will run multiple times (one for each login)

It's an infinite loop that I want running provided a user is logged in, but not more than once for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `bash(1)` is run as a login shell (i.e., when the user log in) it runs `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` unless invoked with `--no-profile`. Starting your script from there should do the trick.

Comment: This is the right approach. Unfortunately some X window managers don't run a login shell: they just give you an X session and you start ordinary xterms yourself. So it may or may not work for your setup.

Answer (score 3):

Your script should check that there is only one instance.  Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir ~/.lock_script || exit
trap "rmdir ~/.lock_script" EXIT

while true
do
    # Do whatever the script does continuously, here....
    #
done
```

The `trap` command takes care of cleaning up on exit, so even if the script is killed or terminated, it will clean up.  No process can catch (trap) the TERM signal (Signal 9) so if you `kill -9` the script, it will not clean up after itself.

mkdir is an atomic operation as far as the kernel is concerned.  If the mkdir does not succeed (Eg if the directory already exists) then the command returns an error, which causes the second half of the command to run - eg exit.

You can read the command as "mkdir or else exit" - it is better explained here: http://initialprogramload.blogspot.com/2008/11/single-script-instance.html

I would also suggest that you should not use `while true` in this way - try if at all possible to think of another way of doing whatever you want to do.

Comment: I am using `inotifywait` in the `while true` to execute another script every time a file is changed.

Comment: @trideceth12 have you tried solution that I have posted ?

Comment: I found the `mkdir` + `trap` suggestions pretty helpful, +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more condition as below :

add in `.bashrc`

```
export my_script_pid=myscript.${USER}
[[ ! -f $my_script_pid ]] && { touch $my_script_pid; echo run-script; } || echo "script already running"
```

then in your script add `rm $my_script_pid` at the last.

Comment: +1 Good work around solution. But there should be something in *nix to run a program once per login.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script and can get the logs from the below command:

```
nohup /path/to/your/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

It will also give you the output.

Comment: hey you are sending output to `/dev/null` then how will give output ??

Comment: OP don't want this, please read question again then reply carefully